# Size to power trade off with solar panels

Tags: solar-cell, voltage

I'm looking to power a remote controlled car with a solar panel on its back.

What size to power am I going to get?  Is there one light enough that it wont slow the car down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is dependent on what you are willing to pay. A remote controlled car pulls Amps of power normally, you will not be able to sustain this with a solar panel you can afford and is not too large.

If you want to use a solar panel for recharging the battery during down time this is very possible.

Solar panels are based on a watts per square inch they can achieve. They are still normally sold with a wattage rating.

The amount of available power is quite variable. Most marketing give you an absolute best case. Things that cause great variance are...

1. Alignment to light source. Yes,
   being off-angle from the sun is bad.
2. Amount of light available. Small
   variance of conditions can have a
   large affect.
3. Light source. florescent and the sun
   are very different, there are panels
   for each.
   There can be many more variables, but these alone will account for  you getting less than 10% of what it is rated in most cases.

If I get a chance tomorrow I will look up more information for you.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, average solar panels wont put out enough power to run most RC cars. The exception are expensive high quality solar panels, combined with very carefully engineered lightweight & efficient car.

Answer (score 1):

Modern silicon solar panels provide 100 to 150 Watts per square meter of panel when pointed directly at the sun at midday. (9 to 14 Watts per square foot of panel). For a model size panel that's 10 to 15 **milliWatts** per square centimetre.

This will be reduced to about 20% - 50% for bright cloudy conditions, 5% - 10% when very "overcast" but still somewhat bright. You will get almost no power from indoor lighting.

On your model, if you managed a 100 mm x 150 mm (4" x 6") panel - same size as a typical small photograph - that would be 10 x 15 = 150 square centimetres or 1500 to 2250 milliWatts - say 1.5 atts in practice. That's large compared to the panels you see on most small portable device.

If you could save all this energy to battery at 100% efficincy (you can't) and retrieve it with 100% efficiency (same) then you'd get "1 Watt hour" of energy per hour of sunlight.

On a sunny Sydney December day [the wonderful Gaisma solar data site](http://www.gaisma.com/en/location/sydney-au.html) says you effectively get 6 hours of full sunshine.

So, on Australia's best days you'd get 1.5 Watts x 6 hours = 9 Watt-hours of energy. Let's call that 10 Watt-hours to make arithmetic easier.

This means that after a day of Sydney summer sun charging you can run

> A 100 milliWatt motor for 100 hours
>   A 1 Watt motor for 10 hours
>   A 10 Watt motor for 1 hour
>   A 100 Watt motor for 0.1 hours = 6 minutes.
>   A 1 kiloWatt motor for 0.01 hours = 36 seconds.

In the real world things don't scale quite so nicely - the faster you take  energy from a battery the less efficient it gets. Lets ignore that for now.

A 100 mW (milliWatt) motro can be useful but is too small for driving a model car.
A 1 Watt motor will allow a small toy with efficient gearbox etc to wander around slowly.
10 Watts starts to get energetic but is far from RC racing style.
100 Watts is very capable and would hake many people happy - probably below the very top RC power level.
1 KiloWatt :-) !!!!!

So - to get RC levels of performance you get about 1 minute of running per hour of charging.
A 10 Watt motor will run for about 10 minutes per hour of charging.
And a 1 Watt or so motor wild run in direct sunlight - as would be expected with a 1.5 Watt panel.